# How do you host a NextJs (FrontEnd), Express(Backend) and Firebase (Database) stack app?

Tags: firebase, express, next.js, rabbitmq

I have an app that needs to communicate with a RasberryPI using RabbitMQ, therefore I plan on using amqplib in an express backend and I have a database for images, logs and data for offline usage.

What the simplest method or service to host such an app?

I thought of using Vercel but it does not support custom servers only Serverless functions. Next was Firebase but I cannot find documentation on integrating multiple frameworks.

Comment: rent a 15$/month vps 2~4 GB ram, 20G disk, use docker for each app, ssh/docker good assets and has similar complexity with google cloud/aws/etc

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options. I would recommend staying with Cloud Run. It plays very nicely with Firebase and can deploy NodeJS and NextJS applications.

For the NextJS application, be sure to add a Dockerfile like these instructions suggest: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker#in-existing-projects